# React native when assigning the value of object changing randomly

Tags: react-native

I am assigning constant object value to temporary state object, and while making changes to temporary object, the constant object value is also getting changed

I have declared one constant object value

```
 const dict ={  
    '2019-07-10': [{text: 'Dr Eddie A Rosa'},{text: 'Dr Shahida N Siddiqui'}],  
    '2019-07-11': [{text: 'Dr Dae W Lee'}],
   '2019-07-12': [{text: 'Dr Lisa F Brodkin'},{text: 'Dr Eddie A Rosa'}]}
```

and my state is like

```
export default class ScheduleCalendar extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
this.state = { tempdict:{}}
}
```

On the function invoke i am assigning the value of const  dict to temporary dict and manipulating the temporary dict

```
ondaypress =(date) => {
// Here date value is '2019-07-11'
        console.log('Inside the update markers of calendar.js new')


 this.setState({ tempdict: Object.assign({}, dict) }, () => 
{
 if(this.state.tempdict[date]) // Checking whether tempdict has the key date or not
        {
            this.state.tempdict[date].push({text:'Dr Beth' }) 
        }
        else{
          this.state.tempdict[date] = [{text:'Dr Beth'}]
        }
    })     
     }
    }
```

Here both the objects tempdict and dict is getting changed we are getting output as

```
dict={
'2019-07-10': [{text: 'Dr Eddie A Rosa'},{text: 'Dr Shahida N Siddiqui'}],
'2019-07-11': [{text: 'Dr Dae W Lee'},{text:'Dr Beth'}],
'2019-07-12': [{text: 'Dr Lisa F Brodkin'},{text: 'Dr Eddie A Rosa'}]
}

tempdict ={
'2019-07-10': [{text: 'Dr Eddie A Rosa'},{text: 'Dr Shahida N Siddiqui'}],
'2019-07-11': [{text: 'Dr Dae W Lee'},{text:'Dr Beth'}],
'2019-07-12': [{text: 'Dr Lisa F Brodkin'},{text: 'Dr Eddie A Rosa'}]}
```

Expected was that tempdict should only be changed dict should not be changed

dict should be like

```
dict ={
'2019-07-10': [{text: 'Dr Eddie A Rosa'},{text: 'Dr Shahida N Siddiqui'}],
'2019-07-11': [{text: 'Dr Dae W Lee'}],
'2019-07-12': [{text: 'Dr Lisa F Brodkin'},{text: 'Dr Eddie A Rosa'}]
}
```

We have tried Object.freeze() too but the same result we are getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign an object to the state it will store object **reference** too That's why when you add or remove anything from a state it will affect all the referenced objects. 
So first you have to convert an object Using **JSON.parse** and **JSON.stringify** before assigning.

Replace your object assign code `Object.assign({}, dict)` with
`Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dict))`